# Node.sj TypeError: req.check is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito, express-validator

I've read many answers here and googled it but nothing works

I've installed:

```
npm i express-validator 
npm install express-validator@6.7.0 --save-exact
```

in my code I use it like this

```
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(expressValidator());
req.check('email', 'Invalid email').isEmail();
req.check('psw', 'Password must have at least 8 characters').isLength({min: 8});
```

I get the error `Node.sj TypeError: req.check is not a function`
as well as `TypeError: expressValidator is not a function`

Comment: I don't see a use of the default import used as a function in the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/).

Comment: You cannot use express-validator's latest version as a middleware. Also req.check is the old syntax and used in legacy version. For using express-validator now youll have to import the module in your middleware file and use different functions offered by express-validator like body, params etc. You can read documentation on how to implement it https://express-validator.github.io/docs/